# Best way to save a 2D array of String for Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, save, 2d

I've build my games levels around a 2D String array but I can't figure out how to save that array to the phones memory then load it again. Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your level is static, you can create the game level in a text file, add this to your project in /assets folder and load this file with something like:

```
InputStream is = yourContext.getAssets().open("level.txt");
```

And parse file for load in 2D String array.